# Quick Explode Modifier in Blender Internal Does Not Affect All Objects

Tags: rendering, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, particles, add-on

I'm not sure if this problem is common, but I was working with the *Quick Explode* modifier, and in the pre-rendered scene it worked alright, even when I pressed rendered view, but after I actually rendered it, the exploded object remained visible.

[image: Pre rendered (everything is ok)]

Pre rendered (everything is ok).

[image: Post rendered (2 of the exploded Islands to the left are still there)]

Post rendered (2 of the exploded Islands to the left are still there).

Comment: Could you upload a .blend file?

Answer (score 4):

With quick explode, under the modifier settings ensure that *dead* is not ticked on.
[image]

Otherwise, the particles will not disappear after their lifetime. Under default settings, this is the only reason that I know of that the particles should remain. If your animation is shorter than 50 frames however, which is the default, then go to the *particle tab* and change the lifetime of the objects particle system as needed.

[image]